# R - Make lines() points/line thickness reflect density of points?

Tags: r, plot

I know how to change the thickness of points/lines manually; however I wish to plot 1000+ series on the same graph so that the resulting graph has darker or lighter points depending on the density of points at that location. ie, the more points centered there the darker the area gets.

What I have now is just this:

```
plot(df[,1],ylim=c(0,1))
for(i in 2:ncol(df)){
   lines(df[,i],col='grey',type='p')
}
```

Which gives me the following graph. Unfortunately there's so many points that it just gives me a uniform grey line, instead of telling me how these points are distributed.

[image]

Comment: You can alter the transparency of points like `#000000` representing a "black" colour, like `col="#00000033"` so that the darkness will build up gradually. Also see `?smoothScatter`

Comment: The first suggestion is exactly what I'm after, thanks!